# Git Works Out of the Box in Hudson; Can't Even Install Plug-In in Jenkins

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

So after reading multiple Q&As here about why I should use Jenkins over Hudson, I went ahead and made the switch ... and now I'm regretting it.  With Hudson (or at least with the Debian package I used to install Hudson), Git came "out of the box"; I didn't have to install any plug-ins or anything.

With Jenkins however, not only do I need a separate plug-in, but when I try to install that plug-in, it fails, repeatedly.  I can find the plug-in in the list of available plug-ins, check it, and get a "success" message, but after I restart Hudson the plug-in isn't there (and it's once again on the available plug-ins list).

The problem might be the warning message under the plug-in's description:

> Warning: This plugin is built for Jenkins 2.1.0 or newer. It may or
>   may not work in your Jenkins.

... except there is no 2.1.0 of Jenkins (or even a 2.anything), at least that I can find.

Has anyone else run in to this, and if so do you have any kind of workaround?

Comment: How did you install Jenkins? Did you uninstall the Hudson package first? What version does Jenkins say is running in the bottom right of each page?

Comment: I did install Hudson first (not sure what version, but whatever version is in the Ubundu/Debian package).  The Jenkins version is 1.433.  Interestingly enough there's a link on the manage Jenkins page for "New version of Jenkins (2.1.1) is available for download (changelog)."  ... but when you click the changelog link, it takes you to notes for 1.4.33 :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up purging hudson/jenkins, then re-installing the jenkins package; this time the git plug-in installed successfully!